# nodejs interactive console with logging

Tags: node.js

I have a nodeJS app that currently prints to console during various events and things of that nature.

I'm looking to maintain that logging functionality, while also giving the user the ability to send input and commands. 
Kind of like this:

```
Some logs
Some other logs
Even more logging
an unholy amount of gibberish
/\ Prints on this line and shifts the other lines up /\
> prompt
```

I'm aware you can get user input in a synchronous fashion, where the program would wait until the user input is submitted, but would it be possible to do it like this?

Comment: Apologies in advance if this has already been answered; I've been looking for weeks and haven't found anything like this, so I was curious as to if it was even possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible options:

**prompt**

An easy to use library to build prompts

https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt

**readline**

If you want to build your own code you can manually read the inputs

https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html